# Adding existing Beanshell Listener to every new Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a `Beanshell` Listener which has a certain code written to fetch some metrics during the execution of the script. I want this listener to be appended to every other new `Jmeter` script *automatically* when a user creates a script in Jmeter. Is this possible?

Example:

A user opens a new `Jmeter` script and by default, the `Beanshell` listener created earlier having the code should automatically be there in the script for the thread group rather than adding a new `Beanshell` listener and copy-pasting the code to this newly appended listener. Is this scenario possible? TIA.

Jmeter Version - 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) and come up with your own Template having whatever Test Elements you want and encourage colleagues to use your template for creating the tests.

---

Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is strongly recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it is a good time to consider migration.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see any option of creating a new template. It just shows the existing templates that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy paste code, Just put the file name which contains the script in file name field (can use Browse)

> Script file A file containing the BeanShell script to run. The file name is stored in the script variable FileName

Notice that you better move to JSR223 Listener according to [JMeter's best practice](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting):

> Since JMeter 3.1, we advise switching from BeanShell to JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: sure, I'll try this out.